# Standard deviation of time series

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I wanted to calculate the mean and standard deviation of a sample. The sample is two columns, first is a time and second column, separated by space is value. I don't know how to calculate mean and standard deviation of the second column of vales using python, maybe scipy? I want to use that method for large sets of data.
I also want to check which number of a set is seven times higher than standard deviation.
Thanks for help.

```
time value
 1 1.17e-5
 2 1.27e-5
 3 1.35e-5
 4 1.53e-5
 5 1.77e-5
```

The mean is `1.418e-5` and the standard deviation is `2.369-6`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question, assuming your samplee's dataframe is `df`, the following should work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[1,2,3,4,5], 'value':[1.17e-5,1.27e-5,1.35e-5,1.53e-5,1.77e-5]}
```

`df` will be something like this:

```
>>> df
   time     value
0     1  0.000012
1     2  0.000013
2     3  0.000013
3     4  0.000015
4     5  0.000018
```

Then to obtain the standard deviation and mean of the `value` column respectively, run the following and you will get the outputs:

```
>>> df['value'].std()
2.368966019173766e-06

>>> df['value'].mean()
1.418e-05
```

To answer your second question, try the following:

```
std = df['value'].std()
df = df[(df.value > 7*std)]
```

I am assuming you want to obtain the rows at which `value` is greater than 7 times the sample standard deviation. If you actually want greater than or equal to, just change `>` to `>=`. You should then be able to obtain the following:

```
>>> df
   time     value
4     5  0.000018
```

Also, following @Mad Physicist's suggestion of adding Delta Degrees of Freedom `ddof=0` (if you are unfamiliar with this, checkout [Delta Degrees of Freedom Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics))), doing so results in the following:

```
std = df['value'].std(ddof=0)
df = df[(df.value > 7*std)]
```

with output:

```
>>> df
   time     value
3     4  0.000015
4     5  0.000018
```

P.S. If I am not wrong, its a convention here to stick to one question a post, not two.

Comment: I'm thinking you might want ddof=0 in the standard deviation computation

Comment: @MadPhysicist Hmm you have a point. I'll add your suggestion above :)